# How to assign a JSON array to ag-grid RichSelectCellEditor

Tags: ag-grid

I'm getting an infra table from the database that has two columns

int - ID

string - DESCRIPTION

and I want the ag-grid to add a new row  with the correct pattern:
 a specific cell will have a 'RichSelectCellEditor' or something similar, that displays the DESCRIPTION, but when I select a specific row, I would like to know the ID

for example, when selecting "male", i would like to get '0' value:
[image]

I'm using ag-grid version 17.1.1
and my code of the columnDefs looks something like this:

```
headerName: "blah blah",
field: "someField",
cellStyle:{
    'text-align':"center"
},
editable: true,
cellEditorSelector: function (params){
    return{
        component: ' agRichSelectCellEditor',
        params: {values: vm.ColumnTypes}
    }
}
```

with this code, i see (instead of 'male','female' etc..)

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

in my case,
vm.ColumnTypes looks like this:

```
[
   {"ColumnTypeID":1,"ColumnTypeName":"Boolean"}, 
   {"ColumnTypeID":2,"ColumnTypeName":"String"}, 
   {"ColumnTypeID":3,"ColumnTypeName":"Date"}, 
   {"ColumnTypeID":4,"ColumnTypeName":"Bit"}, 
   {"ColumnTypeID":5,"ColumnTypeName":"Decimal"}, 
   {"ColumnTypeID":6,"ColumnTypeName":"Integer"}
]
```

Comment: provide a part of `vm.ColumnTypes` or full code with plnkr

Comment: I've added vm.ColumnTypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fist, let's have a look on the [doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#agrichselectcelleditor)
>
> **`values`**: List of values to be selected from.

And the short sample from the same link

```
if (params.data.type === 'gender') return {
    component: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
    params: {values: ['Male', 'Female']}
};
```

`params: {values: ['Male', 'Female']}` - `values` should have a **list** of possible values (**not objects**)

In your case, of `objects`, you need to create a workaround for extract, parse and bind the values.

> Let's go deeper

This is a similar code-part of my exact same solution (`objects` with `agRichSelect`)

```
cellEditor = 'agRichSelect';
cellEditorParams= {
    values: this.extractValues(vm.ColumnTypes)
},
valueFormatter=  (params) => {
    return this.lookupValue(vm.ColumnTypes, params.value);
};
valueParser =  (params) => {
    return this.lookupKey(vm.ColumnTypes, params.newValue);
}
```

`extractValues` should return a list of `keys` (Id's) for identification, which would be used to connect the needed values

```
extractValues(mappings) {
    return mappings.map(item=>item.ColumnTypeID);
}
```

`lookupValue` would be used internally by the `ag-grid` to get exact `value` by the `key` (Id)

```
lookupValue(mappings, key) {
    return mappings.find(item=>item.ColumnTypeID==key).ColumnTypeName;
}
```

And the last one `lookupKey` would be used once you will select anything from `combo box` (dropdown input), in case of the `key` (Id) - would be used for binding, we need to retrieve it by the `value`;

```
lookupKey(mappings, name) {
    let key:any;
    for (key in mappings) {
        if (mappings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (name === mappings[key]) {
                return key.ColumnTypeID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventually, I've managed to do something similar to your code, using a filter on the JSON array and a CellRenderer. thank you for your help